# DWR in Grails without Plugin

Tags: grails, dwr

I want to use DWR without using their plugin in grails..Their plugin is no good with no documentation and does not supports latest version..
How can i achieve this..?

Comment: IS there a reason you have to use DWR ? Won't jQuery or prototype do the job for you ?

Comment: I need to implement Chat and other functionality in which server sends a response to the client.So DWR sopports some reverse Ajax technology like a COMET

Comment: So does JQuery : http://cometd.org/documentation/cometd-javascript

Comment: This is an implementation of COMET by DOJO..As DWR also gives their implementation of COMET..